# Cleaning Acetone residue on sink stopper

Tags: sink, cleaning

I left some acetone in a sink for around 90 minutes and it turned white. From scraping at stopper I found that it appears to be a residue or at least surface level damage. What is the best way to remove this residue?

[image: Sink stopper after acetone]

Comment: acetone evaporates cleanly, so it should/can't leave a residue. If something was left behind, certainly new acetone will remove it. I suspect however that it dissolved coloring of the material, which can't really be fixed.

Comment: thinking about it more, I would try more acetone; the mark could be a deposit of minerals dissolved by the acetone and left behind on the stopper when it evaporated. If they dissolved once with acetone, they have to dissolve again with acetone. Just wipe it up before it dries this time...

Comment: Be very careful about leaving acetone around in the open without a lot of ventilation - it evaporates easily and you don't want an explosive mix of acetone vapour in air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried what [dandavis](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/68917/dandavis) suggested in the comments and used more acetone to dissolve the residue and it worked. It allowed me to remove the residue to the point to where it now looks close to the way it did originally.